# Windows 10 upgrade screen dimming

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, hyperlink

My Dell computer (all-in-one, less that one year old) came loaded with Windows 8. I partook of the Windows 10 upgrade. After it last updated (today) when I hover over a link on a webpage the screen dims. When I roll away from the link the screen goes back to full brightness. This never happened before the upgrade. Other than that everything is fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I just ran into this problem myself when I use Chrome.

It seems like this happens when Chrome tries to show the toolbar at the bottom.  It was fixed when I turned off hardware acceleration.  Go to Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> UNCHECK Use Hardware Acceleration.